How to Live Reload golang REST project like nodemon in nodejs?
I want to run golang REST api project in echo labstack.
for development purpose i want that when i save file it automatically refesh the api's in VS code like nodemon does in nodejs.
i am trying to go run main.go each time to execute updated code.
but i want that it should execute updated code automatically.

I haven't used it myself but there's this https://github.com/cosmtrek/air

I started using this via running air server command it worked smoothly
